# Redirect website site/landing for domain to elsewhere?

Tags: security, http, dns, domain-name

Is it possible for crook to redirect website site/landing to your domain to elsewhere?  Say, a visitor's intended website is, `knowledgenotebook.com`, but the crook redirected the user to `google.com` or `yahoo.com` or anything else?  And doing so randomly, so, it can try to avoid detection.

Comment: I like the word "crook" very much.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do that with [DNS cache poisoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_cache_poisoning) or [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

With DNS poisoning it would still say knowledgenotebook.com in the URL.  With XSS i think it would have to have the new URL.

What do you mean by randomly?  As in user X will get redirected but users Y and Z will not?  If that is what you mean then they could probably randomize it with XSS.  I don't think it could be randomized using DNS poisoning...

Comment: Or they could use a BHO or other client-side plug-in to mess with things. The options are, if not endless, at least vast.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. He can use several techniques to achieve that like DNS hijacking, IP spoofing, ARP poisoning, edition of hostfile etc. [Hakin9](http://hakin9.org/) is a very good magazine for beginners (but not only) interested in security matter

Comment: There's so many ways to do this, and which is easiest depends on many factors

Comment: & David Heise, the thing is it then it would distract me from focusing on the marketing of the software... it looks like the being is fking deeply evil...

Comment: @Don Don: What do you mean by marketing on the software? Since marketing I think, is a separate sphere of the software industry.(?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he can do it by modifying the [hostsfile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file)

Comment: Or, if they're feeling ambitious, hijack the authoritative DNS entry, so it affects more than just the one machine. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The best way for your users to ensure that they are actually getting your site is to use an SSL certificate. The HTTPS protocol requires browsers to verify that the domain name it is trying to get matches the domain name of the certificate (otherwise you'll get a security warning in your browser).

There's not really any way to prevent all the possible ways that someone can do this, as it can happen anywhere between your server and the user. [DNSSEC](http://www.dnssec.net/) is supposed to help with some of these issues, like cache poisoning.

Comment: That's helpful, but there are ways to fake that out, too. In particular, SSL's weak point at this time is in the certificate generation, not the protocol itself. Too many entities -- many of whom are easily-bribed, third-world agencies -- are capable of issuing certificates.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: he have written that there is no way to prevent it. And SSL's weakest point were always security holes. While it brings some security it also brings a lot of other vulnerables. And SSL can not prevent attacks like server-side code injections for example.

Comment: Guys, thank you very much.  I've received pretty encouraging feedback about the little program that I wrote to help college students and the website stats (2 tools) indicates 22% entry page is the download page (which has to recommended since I never give it out.  But why is traffic excessively low like 30 or 40 unique visits per day?  I know some powerful org is behind a popular website and email admin tool, that is, they would be able to do a lot of damage if some of their ppl acts crazy but an FBI agent told me very unlikely & I would be horrible if I'm wrong in my speculation. thoughts?